# Java MVC Implementation

Tags: java, mvc, java-8

I am trying to write an MVC based application from scratch using Java 8 and Swing... I am having some difficulties with this.

I want to know if I am going the correct way about this...

My controller code is:

```
public class Controllerv2 {
private final Map<String, View> views = new HashMap<>();
private final Map<String, Command> commands = new HashMap<>();

private final ModelContainer model = new ModelContainer(this);

public void addView(String key, View view) {
    views.put(key, view);
}

public View getView(String key) {
    return views.get(key);
}

public void showView(String key) {
    getView(key).showForm();
}

public void addCommand(String commandString, Command cmd) {
    commands.put(commandString, cmd);
}

public void executeControllerCommand(String commandString) {
    commands.get(commandString).execute();
}
}

public abstract class View {
protected final JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
protected final GUIAction guiAction = new GUIAction();
protected final Controllerv2 controls;
```

Views are subclassed from this class:

```
public View(Controllerv2 suppliedController) {
    this.controller = suppliedController;
}
// Fires up the form
protected abstract void initComponents();

// Package up the fields into an object of type T and return
public abstract <T> T readFields();

// Self explanatory functions
public void showForm() {dialog.setVisible(true);}
public void hideForm() {dialog.setVisible(false);}

// For fields that need updating
public abstract void updateFields(String[] msg);     
}
```

This is an example of a concrete View:

```
public final class VBasexLoginR extends View {    
private JButton connectButton;
private JLabel connectionLabel;
private JTextField hostField;
private JLabel hostLabel;
private JLabel passwordLabel;
private JButton pingButton;
private JTextField portField;
private JLabel portLabel;
private JPasswordField pwField;
private JLabel titleLabel;
private JTextField uidField;
private JLabel userId;

public VBasexLoginR(Controllerv2 c) {
    super(c);
    initComponents();
}

@Override
protected void initComponents() {// Boilerplate to setup the form}


@Override
public BaseXCredentials readFields() {
    return new      BaseXCredentials(hostField.getText(),portField.getText(),uidField.getText(),pwField.getPassword());
}

@Override
public void updateFields(String[] msg) {
    connectionLabel.setText(msg[0]);
}
}
```

Am I going in the right direction with this?

Also, I think I may need different models, one for running queries on BaseX and then ones for working with the results. Thus far I have...

```
public class ModelContainer {
private final Map<String, Model> models = new HashMap<>();
private final Map<String, ModelCommand> commands = new HashMap<>();
private final Controllerv2 controller;

ModelContainer(Controllerv2 suppliedController) {
    this.controller = suppliedController;
}

public void addModel(String key, Model model) {
    models.put(key, model);
}

public Model getModel(String key) {
    return models.get(key);
}

public void addCommand(String key, ModelCommand cmd) {
    commands.put(key, cmd);
}

public void executeModelCommand(String key) {
    commands.get(key).execute();
}
}
```

Views can be got at through the `getView` method in `controls`

Is this correct or is this overkill?

EDIT -- Taking into account Mat's Mug response, changed the code to reflect the naming conventions suggested.

Comment: The silence says it all... Back to the drawing board!

Comment: Hi @swshaun! Welcome to code review. It takes some time to write a quality review (we're all about quality here), so it takes a little longer to get an answer than other stack exchange sites. Why not browse some other Q&As while you wait?

Comment: Okey pokes.... Thank you @ckuhn203 Sorry for flipping my lid! Thank you -- I have been frustrated a bit with MVC for a while now.

Comment: No worries. We've all been there. Feel free to stop by our [chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor) if you like too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm only going to *scratch the surface* here, and leave more seasoned [java](/questions/tagged/java) reviewers take a stab at this one, for I've never written a line of [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8) - but some concepts transcend language barriers.

Naming in particular.

#### Signatures can, and *should* talk.

> ```
> public void addView(String viewString, View view) {
>     views.put(viewString, view);
> }
>
> public View getView(String viewString) {
>     return views.get(viewString);
> }
> ```

Take this line:

> ```
> public void addView(String viewString, View view) {
> ```

The name `viewString` is pretty confusing. One has to *look at how it's implemented* to go "oh, that's a *key* for a hashmap!". How about this instead?

```
public void addView(String key, View view) {
```

Now there's no ambiguity whatsoever, and `getView(String key)` becomes crystal-clear.

#### Consistency is King

This is just a minor thing, but I'd prefer consistency in the choice of verbs used to describe an action. For example, if a form *is a view* and a form gets *shown*, then a view should be *shown* too, not *opened*:

> ```
> public void openView(String viewString) {
>     getView(viewString).showForm();
> }
> ```

Would be

```
public void showView(String viewString) {
    getView(viewString).showForm();
}
```

Same with *commands* - if a command *executes*, I wouldn't want the verb *run* to refer to the same thing, I'd prefer it be consistent:

> ```
> public void runControllerCommand(String commandString) {
>     commands.get(commandString).execute();
> }
> ```

Would be:

```
public void executeControllerCommand(String commandString) {
    commands.get(commandString).execute();
}
```

#### Single-letter identifiers

Don't. This:

> ```
> ModelContainer(Controllerv2 c) {
>     this.controls = c;
> }
> ```

Is pretty darn confusing. Does `c` stand for *controller*, or for *controls*? Actually there seems to be something fishy going on here, "controls" is a nice name for a *collection of controls*, but you have it as ..a `Controllerv2` (is there a `Controllerv3`? Avoid "versioning" classes like this, especially in the *early development stages*). Notice the puzzled expression in my face? ;)

Anyway, that `c` would probably be better of as `controller`.

---

#### Constructor arguments

I like this part - `final` makes your intent very clear:

> ```
> private final Map<String, Model> models = new HashMap<>();
> private final Map<String, ModelCommand> commands = new HashMap<>();
> private final Controllerv2 controls;
>
> ModelContainer(Controllerv2 c) {
>     this.controls = c;
> }
> ```

I'd push it a step further though, and provide a way to initialize the class with models and commands, like this:

```
private final Map<String, Model> models = new HashMap<>();
private final Map<String, ModelCommand> commands = new HashMap<>();
private final Controllerv2 controller;

ModelContainer(Controllerv2 controller, Map<String, Model> models, Map<String, ModelCommand> commands) {
    this.controller = controller;
    this.commands = commands;
    this.models = models;
}
```

And now the client code doesn't need to call `AddCommand` 20 times when there's that many commands to add.

---

#### Indentation

Your indentation is a little off, too. Whenever a code file ends like this:

```
}
}
```

You know something's gone wrong. I'd blame it on the Java-style braces but that's just the [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) mug talking, just select all but the signature and last closing brace, and give that <kbd>Tab</kbd> button some lovin' ;)

Comment: Thank you -- so am I heading in the correct direction using this approach?

Comment: I don't know enough of the Java UI frameworks to tell, like I said I'm only scratching the surface. I'm sure more answers will come :)

Comment: @swshaun actually looking again there *is* something that tickles: I don't think it's right for the *view* to know anything about a *controller*: seems like you have a circular reference in there; doesn't Java have something like *delegates*, or *events*?

Comment: Ah good spot -- to be honest I have a small MVC project I want to refactor into something less coupled (hence the array of views and models)